# Convert row to unknown column

Tags: ms-access

I have table ITEM of

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D
5  | E
6  | F
```

If I Enter : 2 I want the table to be like that

```
ID | NAME_1 | NAME_2
--------------------
1  | A      | B
2  | C      | D
3  | E      | F
```

If I Enter : 3 I want the table to be like that

```
ID | NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3
-----------------------------
1  | A      | B      | C
2  | D      | E      |
```

What is the query to achieve that? (My db is Ms-Access)

Answer (score 1):

First, create a query, *QParts*, to build the field names:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    P Short;
SELECT 
    ([ID] - 1) \ [P] + 1 AS NewID, 
    "NAME_" & CStr(([ID] - 1) Mod [P] + 1) AS FieldName, 
    Itemx.NAME AS [Value]
FROM 
    Item;
```

Then create a crosstab query:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    P Short;
TRANSFORM 
    First(QParts.Value) AS NewValue
SELECT 
    QParts.NewID
FROM 
    QParts
GROUP BY 
    QParts.NewID
PIVOT 
    QParts.FieldName;
```

Output, P = 2:

[image]

Output, P = 3:

[image]

Comment: your answer works very well as expected only if ID is in sequence and there no gaps.
If I have ID = 1,2,3,4,8,9,10 It will not work as expected. The un-exist Id will be presented as blank. but very good answer indeed. thank you

Comment: OK. We only have your sample data. For different methods to add sequential numbers, se my project [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).